# CORB não permite mostrar resposta JSON

Tags: angular, web-service, cors

Forneceram uma API que retorna o seguinte JSON:

```
{
    "ResponseStatus": {
        "ResponseCode": 0,
        "ResponseMessage": "Success."
    },
    "Events": [
        {
            "CodEspec": 65957,
            "NomeEspec": "O PIOR ESPETÁCULO        DO MUNDO",
            "DiaHoraEspecs": [
                "2019-05-09T21:30:00",
                "2019-05-10T21:30:00",
                "2019-05-25T21:30:00"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Estou a desenvolver o front-end em Angular e para tal criei este model:
Evento.ts

```
export class Event{
  CodEspec: number;
  NomeEspec: string;
  DiaHoraEspecs: Date[];
}
```

Além disso criei um serviço para obter o JSON com a seguinte funcionalidade:

```
  getEventos():Observable<Event[]>{
    //get todos os eventos
    return this.http.get<Event[]>(`${this.ticketlineUrl}`);
  }
```

Depois no componente chamado evento chamei o serviço e o GET para retornar a resposta e depois mostrar.

events.component.ts

```
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {

  events: Event[];

  constructor(private ticketlineservice: TicketlineService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ticketlineservice.getEventos().subscribe(events => {
      this.events = events;
    });
  }
}
```

events.component.html

```
<div>
    <ul *ngFor="let event of events">
        <li>Evento: {{ event.title }}
                {{ event.CodEspec }}
                {{ event.NomeEspec }}
                {{ event.DiaHoraEspecs }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Problema:** Não mostra qualquer informação, e a consola mostra os seguintes erros:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "", ok: false, …}

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Já usei uma extensão do chrome que resolve o problema do Access-Control-Allow-Origin, mas o CORB mantém-se e não mostra qualquer informação.

Comment: vc tem que habilitar o cors no seu backend

Comment: O back-end não é meu, eu queria uma opção para testar o front-end.